# Index/Import a large JSON file into Elasticsearch (>10GB) and add filters

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to python and elastic search and I want to import a 14GB JSON file into Elasticsearch that looks like this:

```
{
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_index": "newsvit",
  "_source": {
    "content": "   \u0628\u0647 \u06af\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0634 \u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0646\u0627\u060c \u062a\u06cc\u0645 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062a\u0631\u0627\u06a9\u062a\u0648\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0632\u06cc ",
    "title": "\u0641\u06cc\u0646\u0627\u0644 \u062c\u0627\u0645 \u062d\u0630\u0641\u06cc\u061b \u0648\u062f\u0627\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0632 \u062d\u0627\u062c\u06cc \u067e\u0648\u063",

    "lead": "\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646 - \u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0646\u0627 - \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0627\u0631 \u067e\u0627\u06cc\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u062c\u0627\u0645 f.",
    "agency": "36",
    "date_created": 1494521741,
    "url": "http://www.irna.ir/fa/News/82525960/",
    "image": "uploads/2017/05/11/2561366787.jpg",
    "category": "5"
  },
  "_type": "news",
  "_id": "2981938"
}
```

I wanted to import this file using logstash but I have 2 problems now:

1)

I wrote this .conf file for importing it:

```
input {
    file {
        start_position => "beginning"
        path => "E:/git/consemsearch/ferdowsi-data.json"
        sincedb_path => "NULL"
    }
}
filter {
   json {
       source => "message"
   }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
         hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "news_data"
    }
    stdout { }
}
```

but it doesn't add the filters I want to it. I want to be able to filter it in Elasticsearch/Kibana by items in `_source` and `_id`. How can I write the correct .conf?

2)
This file is very large and it takes too long to import with logstash. is there a faster way of importing it?

Comment: by filter do you mean, I don't want to import files in elastic if Ids are in [] or source contains something ?

Comment: @Jaycreation I mean I want to be able to make queries on these data based on fields in the source object, like filter based on category for example

Comment: you will note be able to do this on the file input. The file input just read and give you the current line. What you can do is drop an event (don't send it to your output) if it match a condition https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

to "filter" data from input to output, you can use the "[drop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html)" filter:

```
filter {
      if [category] == "old category" {
        drop { }
      }
    }
```

About performance.
It will depends a lot on your hardware.
In your example all is on your localhost. You are trying to read 14gb of data and insert it in the same HDD.
Your HDD IO are probably the bottleneck here. But it can come from RAM or something else.

If you system is able to manage it you can add workers or increase the batch size at the logstash side.
At the elasticseach side you should begin by disabling replicas and increase the index.refresh_interval while you are ingesting your first dataset.

To about optimization:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html